# Launch doc file with javascript in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want to launch a doc file in my C:// once a  is clicked in my html page

Below my code

```
<a href="C://mytestfile.doc">Click Me To launch the DOC FILE</a>
```

unformtunatly, what I'm getting is the "mytestfile.doc" downlowded and not opened in chrome

Comment: Didn't you mean "launch" ?

Comment: Lunchtime!!! You will need `href="file:///<filePath>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter a [file URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) like `file:///C:/path/to/file.txt` but the behaviour would change depending on where that's pointing to:

- If it's a directory, it will show its content in Chrome.
- If it's a know media type (images, audio, video, pdf, ...) it will play/display in Chrome in the usual way.
- If it's an unknown media type, like a Word document, it will just trigger a download.

If the file you want to open is not in the local file system but hosted somewhere, you can should check the [Office URI Schemes documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes). You would end up with something like this:

```
ms-word:ofe|u|http://website.com/document.docx
```

The full schema is:

```
< scheme-name >:< command-name >"|"< command-argument-descriptor > "|"< command-argument >
```

The first part is the scheme name (protocol), which is specific for each Office product:

- `ms-word`
- `ms-powerpoint`
- `ms-excel`
- `ms-visio`
- `ms-access`
- `ms-project`
- `ms-publisher`
- `ms-spd`
- `ms-infopath`

The second part is the command name and its arguments (pars for argument descriptor + argument value), all separated with `|`:

- `ofv|u|` (open for view), followed by the URI to open in view mode.
- `ofe|u|` (open for edit), followed by the URI to open in edit mode.
- `nft|u|` (new document from template), followed by the URI to the template.

  Optionally, you can add a second argument, `s`, with the URI of the folder where you want to save it, so it will end up looking like this:

  ```
  ms-word:nft|u|http://website.com/template.dotx|s|https://website/docs
  ```